# How can I make strings automatically in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, string, automation

Now, I'm learning Python and I want to make a dictionary, where the user can add words (in first step just the word, later definition).

```
word = input('Write a word here')
print('You added ' + word)
```

So, what I would like is the user can add more word, and the program save it to other string.
How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please provide a proper output sample.

Comment: for a dictionary with 3 user input words as keys and None values: `dict.fromkeys(input('Write a word here') for i in range(3))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: It seems more likely that the questioner wants a dictionary in the sense of a compendium of words, not in the sense of the Python data structure. Whether a `dict` is appropriate, and what such a dict might look like, would depend on what they want to do with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this could be done in a `while`-loop where the loop-condition variable is updated upon user input:

```
continue_condition = True
words = []

while continue_condition:
    word = input("Write a word here")
    words.append(word)
    continue_condition = input("Would you like to add another word? Then please type `Y`") == "Y"
```

If you want to populate a dictionary instead of a list, just adapt this code to your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

this will help to automate:

```
dict = {} # variable to store the key and value 

def add():  # add function to add more word in our dictionary.
    word = input('enter the word:  ') # take the user input
    dict[word] = word;  # this will add the word to our dict for simplicity this is sample so we are using the same key and value.
    if('y' == input('do you want to add more word (y/n): ')): # check if user want to add more word to dictionary.
        add() # if yes the call function again ---recursion.

add() # call function for add word for first time.

print(dict) # print all the words in our dict.
```